# How to make LuaLaTeX use ImageMagick Instead of Inkscape for converting SVGs?

Tags: luatex, svg, inkscape, lualatex-dev

I need to use **ImageMagick** instead of **Inkscape** for converting `svg`s to `pdf`s in order to include graphics to my document.

I've found this paragraph [in the `svg and svg-extract` manual](http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/doc/latex-overview/svg.pdf):

[image]

This is what I've done so far:

- I don't have `InkScape` installed. (I've removed the one)
- Added a `convert` (which is **ImageMagick**) to `shell_escape_commands` in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf`
- Command prompt: `lualatex --shell-escape -output-directory=build -aux-directory=build/a -include-directory=src test.tex`

[image]

My tex file:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\author{}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{svg}                    % <-----------
\usepackage[convert]{svg-extract}   % <-----------
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\svgFld{src/images}

\begin{document}

\includesvg{\svgFld/red.svg}

\end{document}
```

The image file is located in the `src/images`.

The output:

```
("|'inkscape' -V ")

Package svg Warning: No version of Inkscape was detected by invoking
(svg)                `inkscape -V'
(svg)                so the Inkscape export will fail quite sure as the
(svg)                command is probably unknown to your OS. You could set
(svg)                `inkscapeversion=<version>' manually but this is very
(svg)                unlikely to work on input line 12.

/bin/sh: 1: inkscape: not found
/bin/sh: 1: inkscape: not found

! Package svg Error: Inkscape version not detected.

See the svg package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.14 \includesvg{\svgFld/red.svg}
```

How do I let the compiler know which converter I want to use and do conversion through **ImageMagick**?

Comment: Package `svg` is designed to use Inkscape for the conversion from SVG to either EPS, PDF or PS and after this step optionally use ImageMagick or Gostscript for a second step conversion to a bitmap format. AFAIK it is not designed to use ImageMagick to convert from SVG to a bitmap format in one step. Maybe you can try to change option `inkscapeexe` (and several other options) to use `magick` instead of `inkscape`.

Comment: It is exactly as @cabohah stated, the usage of Inkscape is mandatory as the main purpose of package `svg` is to use LaTeX for processing all text boxes within the svg file and I am not aware of any other tool than Inkscape which is capable to export to content of those boxes to a separate file.